# Diameter of the Cayley graph of $S_n.$

Tags: group-theory

*Mathematica* uses the generators $(1 2)$ and $(1 2 \dotsc n)$ for the symmetric group $S_n.$ What is the diameter of the Cayley graph with that generating set (symmetrized, so the generators are $(1 2), (1 2 \dotsc n), (n\ n-1 \dotsc 1)?$

Comment: It is known to be $\Theta(n^2)$. See http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Tan.pdf

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks!